# I want to crawl twitter and facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, solr, nutch

I am making a crawler now.
It supports web, Facebook and Twitter.
My mentor says it needs to support getting post using Facebook and Twitter API, but I don't know how.
I am using Solr as a search engine and planning to use Nutch for web crawling.
I saw that Nutch does not support those APIs.
Could you recommend other web crawlers or a way to get posts using Nutch or other ways, whatever.
I would appreciate very much!

Comment: Did you make it in the end?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to crawl in facebook/ twitter?

Only specific search engine bots are allowed to crawl facebook.

Visit https://facebook.com/robots.txt

At the bottom they have disallowed all bots except the one listed.

So to fetch data from facebook (if that's what you need), use API.

https://developers.facebook.com/

In twitter, you can crawl a few url's

```
Allow: /?lang=
Allow: /hashtag/*?src=
Allow: /search?q=%23
```

Again a better approach is to use API, if your aim is to fetch some data.

https://dev.twitter.com/